# Help in evaluating limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help me evaluating the following limit:

If the below limit exist and is non-zero, determine $r$, also evaluate the limit at this value.

How can i find such $r$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n^r \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Comment: Using Stirling is OK?

Comment: What is stirling?? I am new to calculus.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla sorry but i cannot use that. Its is not in my course, any other tool.

Comment: Stolz-Cesaro test?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla what is Stolz-Cesaro test?. Well i am getting very interested in these tools. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: Uhhh...Mr. OP: what is the calculus unit on which you are working that requires you to evaluate a limit like that, but not to use the well-known Stirling limit which makes said evaluation, like, wicked easy?  Please throw the other potential answerers a bone.

Comment: @RonGordon The question looks like $n^r \frac{1.3...(2n-1)}{2.4...(2n)}$. I simplified it to this , but i think this makes it tough.

Comment: Yep, it does.  Do yourself a favor...look at the Stirling approximation.  It is not that hard to grasp.  (The derivation may be a little harder.)  Then plug it in - the answer comes out immediately as I noted.

Comment: @RonGordon true but in my textbook it is not given, how will i convince my teacher in school.

Comment: Again, I ask, what are you given in your textbook?  Might you look up "Stirling" in the index?  Is this problem even in your textbook?

Comment: @RonGordon Yes sir it is. The given things are converting lim to integral, l hopital, sandwich theorom, that is all.Can i convert this to integral.

Comment: OK, let me put it like this: you are not only asking for a limit, you are being asked about *asymptotic behavior*; I know this because of the $n^r$ term.  Asymptotic behavior of factorials *is* the Stirling approximation.  It is that simple.  If the book you are using gives any hint of it being otherwise, then I'd like to know.  But it can't be any easier than applying the Stirling approximation.  At this level, it is silly to imagine otherwise.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you for ur help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Wallis%27s_Product) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the sake of others who might wish to see this done, we know that

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} e^{-n} n^n \quad (n \to \infty)$$

so that, doing the algebra out, we find that

$$\frac{(2 n)!}{2^{2 n} (n !)^2} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

Thus, $r=1/2$ and the limit is $1/\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Calculations are OK but Stirling is verboten.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: for the OP, yes, but sometimes we need to produce an answer for the community.  Stirling is entirely natural here and to be honest, I have no idea what is not verboten to the OP.

Comment: Yes, Stirling was my first idea (see my other comment).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Do you have any ideas of how to attack this problem without using Stirling and keeping it to basic calculus?  If so, then I recommend going that way.  That said, I doubt at this point the OP even knows what (s)he wants.

Comment: *Maybe* with Stolz-Cesaro... but it will be (a bit) hard.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: well, there you go.  And I see the OP doesn't think much of that either.  I will be interested to see what the OP thinks.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is Stirling approximation explained, for large $n $ you have
$$
\ln n! = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln i \simeq \int_1^n\ln x \mathrm {d} x = n\ln n -n( +1)
$$
Or in other words
$$
n!  \simeq n^n e^{-n}.
$$
Sometimes you have to use a more precise approximation which is
$$
n! \simeq n^n e^{-n}\sqrt {2\pi n}.
$$
I'll try to figure out a simpler way later, if I can.

Comment: Sorry only now read about the 'Verbot', my bad.